# HST vacant lot severed from a farm for sale, zoned residential but still has crop on it

Tags: canada, real-estate, hst

I am considering selling a piece of land that was severed as a residential lot from our family farm.  The crop has been planted on it, even though it was legally severed as residential.  If I sell this property do I collect HST on the lot.  It is 1.24acres.

Comment: I don't recognize HST, on a search I found "Harmonized Sales Tax" which is a Canada tax issue. If I am not correct please advise, but for now, I added "Canada" tag to your question. Welcome to SE.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer - http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hst in the wiki.  (randomly found that on another question)

Comment: The world is a big place, other countries might use the same acronym to mean something else, just wanted OP to confirm I guessed right.